# For Loop Returns Last Value In Loop

Tags: java, android

I am learning about For Loops in Java AND Android but I've hit a wall.

My Code:

```
    //01
for (String FilesToDownload : Download) 
    {
         myFILEposter = FilesToDownload;
         fileP();
    }


//02    
private void fileP() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.out.println("Downloading Poster: " +myFILEposter);           
new DownloadFileFromURL2().execute(file_url2 +myFILEposter);

}               


//03
class DownloadFileFromURL2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ...

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

    System.out.println("Downloading Poster: " +myFILEposter);

    ...
```

Note that I have two out prints, one in //02 and the other in //03 which should print the same output, it works in //02 but not in //03. This is what it prints to output:

```
//02

file1
file2
file3
```

AND

```
//03

file3
file3
file3
```

The output in doInBackground is taking the last value in the loop therefore downloading the last file 3 times.

Comment: your doInbackground is using `myfileposter` for output, which is NOT passed in to the method as an argument... so it's pulling that variable from OUTSIDE the function. doinbackground is an async task, so by the time it fires up, your loop has completed, and you end up using whatever the last value in myfileposter is.

Comment: But the doinbackground is called from the for loop 3 times which different values, anyway any idea how i can accomplish what i require?

Comment: but the function doesn't run at the exact moment you call it - it's executed asynchronous. since you're not passing in the value you want to deal with, the function reaches "outside" to get that value. and it does that at time-of-execution, not time-of-calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is fairly horrible, no offense. First off, variables are *lower-case* while class-names are *upper case*. Secondly, methods can take parameters. Assigning a global variable to access in a function is just plain silly. But then you propagate that error into your `AsyncTask` and that's why the whole thing is failing. Cleaning up this mess, you'd get something along the lines of:

```
// oh, please-oh-please, change Download to filesToDownload
for( String aFile : Download ) {
    downloadFile( aFile );
}

private void downloadFile( String whichFile ) {
    System.out.println( "Downloading Poster: " + whichFile );
    new DownloadFileFromURL2().execute( file_url2 + whichFile );
}               


class DownloadFileFromURL2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ...

@Override
protected String doInBackground( String... url ) {

    System.out.println("Downloading Poster: " + url[0] );

    ...
```

So, first you pass the file to download to your `downloadFile()` method as a string. Then you pass that string into your `AsyncTask`... and then **actually use** that parameter by accessing `url[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look into this, url[0] extracts the entire URL while whichFile is null under doInBackground, how can I get file names ONLY without the entire url?

Comment: Well, don't pass in the entire URL. Whatever you pass into `execute()` will wind up in the `url` parameter.